# @Max does not accept 10 digits on long wrapper type

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation

As part of entity definition, @Max(javax.validation.constraints.Max) won't take upper value to validate a 10 digit integer

```
@Min(0)
@Max(9999999999)
@Column(name = "some_column", nullable = false,
    columnDefinition = "INT(10) NOT NULL")
private Integer someColumn;
```

Eclipse floats a red-mark at 2nd line with a message `The value for annotation attribute Max.value must be a constant expression`.

I looked through to find the `MAX_VALUE`for `Integer` only to find it as `2147483647` which is 10 digit as well.

**NOTE:** `hibernate-core:5.0.12`, `validation-api:2.0.0.CR3`

I modified the type to long wrapper

```
@Min(0)
@Max(9999999999)
@Column(name = "some_column", nullable = false,
    columnDefinition = "INT(10) NOT NULL")
private Long someColumn;
```

But, still the error is being stubborn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter to `@Max` is defined as a `long`. Setting it to, for example, `42` means passing the `int` value `42`, which gets cast to the `long` value `42L` and then set. Standard operating procedure, really. Nothing special about `@Max` going on here.

When you pass `9999999999` it tries to interpret it as an `int` and fails. Eclipse is warning you of this, just perhaps not terribly clearly. To pass in `9999999999` you need to do it as a `long` which means designating the constraint as `@Max(9999999999L)`.